# Find any values from a set/list within a string

Tags: search, salesforce, apex

Long time lurker, first time poster. I'm hoping to get some advice from the brilliant minds in this community. In the project I'm working in, the goal is to look at a user-provided string and determine if the content of that string contains any (one or many) matches to a list of match criteria. For example:

User-provided string: "I like thing a and thing b"

Match List:

| Match Criteria | Match Type | Category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Foo | Exact (Case Insensitive) | Bar |
| Thing a | Contains (Case Insensitive) | Things |
| Thing b | Contains (Case Insensitive) | Stuff |

In this case, it would return the following matches:

- Thing a > Things
- Thing b > Stuff

As of now, my approach is to iterate through the match criteria list and check each list item against the user-supplied string using the Match Type specified (Exact, Contains, Regular Expression), returning a list of the matches and then doing some stuff with that list. This approach works, even when matching ~100 rules and handling a 200-record batch, but it seems obvious that the performance will be pretty terrible if a large number of rules is introduced.

Is there a better way to do this that would be supported in Apex called by a trigger? I would love to learn a more sophisticated approach if there is one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What do you need it for. Is it a pure apex exercise or is it "close" to certain standard sObjects? There are lots of built-in features around "fuzzy matching".

In no specific order...

- Have you looked into "all things Einstein", from categorising leads to predicting how likely this opportunity is to close. Might not be direction you expected to take but who knows
- Obviously SOSL comes to mind, like what powers the global search. It automatically does some substitutions for you like Mike -> Michael
- Matching rules, duplicate rules. You'd have a limit of say 5 active rules but you could [hook to them up from Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_Datacloud_FindDuplicates.htm), including creative abuse of the system. "Dear salesforce, let's pretend I'm making such and such Opportunity, can you find me similar Opportunities?" (plot twist- you're not making an Oppty at all, you're creating account of some venture capitalist looking for investments that match his preferences). Give matching rules a go, if not for everything then at least for more creative fuzzy matching. You really don't want to implement soundex, levenshtein etc manually...
- tags? There's somewhat forgotten [feature from SF classic](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.tag_search.htm&type=5), it creates bunch of tables (AccountTag, ContactTag). This plus SOSL could be close to what you need.

Additionally if you need this for anything close to Knowledge Base:

- Data Categories come to mind
- KB supports synonyms, letting you define your (not very intuitive) "thing b => stuff" mapping.
- and it should survive translations